I keep getting this error in XAMPP every time I try to start MySQL. What does the error mean and how can I fix it?
XAMPP gives me an error every time I start MySQL. I checked the error log and this is what it says.

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

mysql produces an error log, which is very comprehensive, if you have problem post the contenet

And did you check out windows event log as suggested by the error message? This error is too generic, we have no way of knowing what exactly went wrong there. Also, xampp has been using mariadb and not mysql for years...

@nbk I just found out about this, thanks. I didn't explore much around cus I've just started using this

@Shadow I'm new to this and I've only started using XAMPP so i dont much about it yet. We're working on databases now in one of my classes and i'm still a bit slow in dealing with these types of errors. Sorry. But yeah I think I'll edit this post to include the more comprehensive error log, cus this one's a bit vague, ty

please don't post inages of code error or logs, but in essence mysql has started without problems

@nbk nope it really doesn't start :(. it keeps generating the same error

the log shows socket create, so the server is available, so you should test it ans try to connect with it via shell or an installed workbench

None of these are errors, just notes. You need to check windows event log as the original error message told you. Please note what server is starting in the 1st line of the screenshot...

You should be using ENGINE=InnoDB.  If you are, 16M is terribly tiny for innodb_buffer_pool_size.  If you have more than 4GB of RAM (likely these days), set that to 70% of available RAM.
Meanwhile, I don't see an actual error message in that screen shot.  (Please use text wherever possible, not images.)
